# Neural Networks for Predictive typing

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, language-model

I don't have a background in neural networks. But, various studies has been proved that neural networks (feed forward / Recurrent) outperformed n-gram language modeling for predicting words in a sequence. But, in an application to text messaging or any text-based conversation, where the language which is most likely used will be more informal or colloquial. Can still a neural networks perform well than n-gram LM? Considering the data to be fed are the text messages (colloquial phrases). If so, please enlighten me, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A neural network is in principle a good choice when you have A LOT of similar data and classification tasks. Predicting the next character (or word... which is just multiple characters) is such a szenario. I don't think it really matters which kind of language you have, as long as you have enough training data of the same kind.

See [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) for a nice article where a recurrent neural network (RNN) was used as a character predictor to write complete texts. They also have code on [github.com/karpathy/char-rnn](https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn) ready to train / go. You can feed it with a start string and ask for the next characters / words.